# Why I'm getting null exceptionj when I run the same function for the second time?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a button over which I call the fucntion `click`
WHen I click the button 2nd time, app crashes.
It is because I call setEdit on null object.
Is there some other way to solve the problem than the second variation
given below with `if(!=null)` ? Is there an explanation why I'm getting this `null` exception ?

```
public void click(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);


    if (editText != null)  { editText.setId(202); }

}
```

But his works fine:

```
public void click(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);


    if (editText != null)  { editText.setId(202); }

}
```

Comment: because you are changing the ID? the second time it's not found anymore using the old ID value. Why are you doing that, anyways?

Comment: @adnan_e I need to `setId` for using programatically defined `editText` from another function. How can I do it without `if(!=null)`; what's the standard way to do it ?

Comment: Don't call setId.  Forget the function exists.  There is NEVER a good reason to change an id of a view.  The only reason it should ever be called is if you're programatically creating views and usually not even then.  If your other function requires a view to have a specific id, your other function needs to be fixed.

Comment: Just to make it clear-  findViewById looks for a view with a matching id.  setId overrides that id, so it is no longer a match.  Once you call setId like that, findViewById will never work for that view again, unless you use the new id.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes,exactly, I'm using programaticaly defined Views. It's very useful for me. Please tell me how do I avoid `null` or point me to some other question/answer.

Comment: No you aren't.  If you were making views programatically, findViewById wouldn't be taking a resource id like that.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm using a `constat 202` which should be used from my other function.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm quite new to this android. How should I set one `id` for ever ? What's the standard way to create `Views` and setId programatically ? I even tried to set at first call `202` and for the second `203` but it still crashes.

Comment: 99.99% of the time, you don't need to set the id.  The reason for having an id is to use findViewById to get a reference to the view.  But when you create the View with new, you already have a reference to the view.  So you just store it in a variable.  The reason to maybe sometimes set an id is deep magic that won't apply to beginners.

Comment: And if you aren't using new to instantiate your views, then you aren't making them programmatically and there's even less reason to set the id.

Comment: @GabeSechan OK. How do I create `Views` programatically and then access it from another function ??

Comment: You store it in a variable, generally at the Activity level.

Comment: @GabeSechan Could you give me here sample code for me to understand ? I need to usem some `public` variable in `OnCreate` right ?

Comment: I posted an answer so I could have nicely formatted code.  Also, you may want to consider learning some command line Java.  From this conversation, you don't seem to have the language quite mastered yet.  Learning it and Android at the same time is a big task.  Learning just the language by itself might be easier.

Comment: @GabeSechan Your answer is what I was looking for. I'm eager to create app for my new mobile phone. Could you please tell me `when` I'm supposed to use `setId` if ever ?

Comment: If you're building the view hierarchy by creating views with the new keyword, and if the view has state that needs to be restored on activity recreation (such as rotation events) and that view is a built in type such as edit text or checkbox and you don't want to write an onSavedInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState function to do that then there might be a usecase.  But generally you use xml and let the compiler assign ids in the compile step.

Comment: Actually there is one other possible usecase-  testing.  You may want to create a view with a specific id to pass into a test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is from the conversation, showing him how to get views and store them.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView text1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    private void someFunc() {
        text1.setText("Hey I used the variable");
    }
}
```